# Where to update new Mosaico templates

Tags: wordpress, mosaico

I want create my Mosaico template in WordPress with the CiviCRM extension
but I can't find where upload the new template.

Secondly, must I activate the new template after uploading it to my host?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see on [Mosaico Extension v2.0-beta3, etal](https://civicrm.org/blog/totten/mosaico-extension-v20-beta3-etal) release, since this version...

> In the CiviCRM menu, you'll find a new item "Administer => CiviMail =>
> Mosaico Settings". This exposes options, such as "Layout" and "Custom
> Template Directory", which would otherwise remain hidden.
>
> (...)
>
> v2.0-beta3 allows site administrators to install templates in the
> "Custom Template Directory", and it allows developers to bundle
> templates into CiviCRM extensions

Answer (score 2):

When you install the Mosaico and related Extensions, you then create the Templates in civicrm and they become available to use in CiviMail, you do not upload them.

ADDENDUM:

If you have installed correctly, as per [instructions](https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico), ie Shoreditch then FlexMailer then Mosaico then at /civicrm/a/#/mosaico-template you should see the word NEW on top of the base template

[image]

Comment: mosaico is an mail builder, it use Template for create mail.
On mosaico you have a base Template : versafix-1... ok 
I want create my own Template.... for use this on mosaico Template builder but I don't find where upload the new Template on my host ?

Comment: see my edit above

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new template through following steps:

1. Create new template folder in mosaico extension directory: packages/mosaico/templates/new_template
2. Copy 'versafix' template to your new template and edit according to your design requirements
3. Register the new template in mosaico extenstion directory in file: CRM/Mosaico/BAO/MosaicoTemplate.php

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hassan how do you do the last step?

Comment: You can do it by adding a new array element in array "$records", like:

$records[] = array(
'name' => 'prizmah-email',
'title' => 'Prizmah Email',
'thumbnail' => CRM_Mosaico_Utils::getTemplatesUrl('absolute', 'prizmah-email/edres/_full.png'),
'path' => 'templates/prizmah-email/prizmah-email.html',
);

Inside if condition of function "findBaseTemplates()"