# how do I create a new template on civicrm / mosaico

Tags: wordpress, custom-templates

Is not a question, i just want to share with you how you can create a new template on civicrm / mosaico!

for wordpress:

Template directory:

```
/www/yoursite/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico/packages/mosaico/templates/
```

here you find 3 templates directory that already exists

choose one of the folders (important)
and duplicate and rename folder and the.html inside (respecte the nomenclature)

next step
view your template in the selection area in wordpress

go to

```
/www/yoursite/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico/js
```

edit index.js

and add your template here:

```
var viewModel = {
        showSaved: ko.observable (false),
        edits: ko.observableArray (initialEdits),
        templates: [{
          name: 'versafix-1', desc: 'The versatile template'
        }, {
          name: 'tedc15', desc: 'The TEDC15 template'
        }, {
          name: 'tutorial', desc: 'The Tutorial'
        }, {
          name: 'newtemplate', desc: 'newtemplatetitle'
        }]
      };
```

Final step is create / modify your own template
put your new template with correct name in your Template directory

sorry for my poor english ... I'm french: p

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Would be nice to format this message properly with _markdown_ formatting to improve legibility.

Comment: What would be helpful would be to change your OP to a question eg For WP how do I create a new template on civicrm / mosaico! Then add your above post as an Answer to your own Question. then we can give you +1 for a useful answer

Comment: I don't understand :(

Comment: @ZeroCool Thanks for posting this. StackExchange has a question and answer format but you have posted your answer as a question.  It would be better to copy most of what you have posted above into the 'Answer' box below.  See https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [template civicrm mosaico on wordpress](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20558/template-civicrm-mosaico-on-wordpress)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for this - it helped me out.

I believe the second part of your answer is no longer valid.

The new place to reference your template seems to be in: `uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico/CRM/Mosaico/BAO/MosaicoTemplate.php`.

Edit the `findBaseTemplates()` method to return another record with your new template's details and it should show up under the `Mailings -> Mosaico Templates` menu option in the `New from base template:` section

Comment: Thanks for your post but this would be better posted as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @WilliamMortada I did try to leave a comment - unfortunately I need 50 reputation to do so :)

Comment: Yes, I appreciate that is a limitation but hopefully you will build up that credit soon. I've just given you 10.