# How can I create a new type of block in Mosaico?

Tags: email, mosaico

The [Mosaico CiviCRM Integration extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/email-template-builder) includes a base template that provides several different types of blocks to use in composing emails.

I need a type of block that's not included in that base template. My block type would contain a name (editable text) on the left, a signature (uploadable image) below the name, and a logo (uploadable image) to the right.

How can I create this custom block type, and make it available in my templates?

Comment: The more modern answer is to [set a custom template directory](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/21977/12).

Answer (score 5):

I believe you can use hook_civicrm_mosaicoBaseTemplates() hook to create your own new mosaico block template definition (alternative to versafix-1).

Documentation on how you can use this hook can be found [here](https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico/blob/2.x/API.md).

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: That link does not work. I am surprised at the limited number of blocks provided. How can we add a bunch more? The versafix-1 base does not come close to produce one of my org's standard newsletters.